# 12 hours to 24 hours conversion gives wrong result

Tags: php, datetime, date-format

I tried converting a 23 hour format  in format `m-d-y h:i` which is march 1st 2014 1 am

```
03-01-2014 01:00 am
```

with

```
date_format('03-01-2014 01:00 am','Y-m-d h:i:s')
date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime('03-01-2014 01:00 am')
```

to its equivalent 24hours format `Y-m-d H:i:s` but i get wrong result

```
2014-01-03 01:00:00
```

it was suppose to give

```
2014-03-01 01:00:00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`03-01-2014 01:00 am` is ambiguous. Is it March 1st? Or April 3rd? From [the manual](https://www.php.net/strtotime):

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; **whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed**.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y h:i a', '03-01-2014 01:00 am');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: You know that. PHP does  not. So it assumes January 3rd.

Comment: You mean January 3rd. But yes, weird US middle-endian dates are probably to blame here.

Comment: You either always specify the date format on input or you do what the person who answered the question said and use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) format. Anything else ends in tears.

Comment: The date has to be displayed in the format am converting from, but stored as the ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) format. thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

For *2005-01-30 11:03 pm* use

```
date('Y-m-d h:i a');
```

For *2005-01-30 23:03* use

```
date('Y-m-d H:i');
```